# Use predefined vue.js directive with custom directive

Tags: vue.js

Suppose I have a custom directive that fetches an array result from certain location , How could I possibly use v-repeat alongside my directive internally rather than separately calling v-repeat externally.

Comment: Having trouble understanding the question. Could you post an example or jsfiddle?

Comment: What i meant was suppose i write a custom directive which obtains a json array from the server then is there a way i could use v-repeat within my directive so that i can bind the array within my directive itself. rather than using a v-repeat externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue, you normally use directives (http://vuejs.org/guide/index.html#Directives) to modify the behavior of an existing DOM element. The behavior you are describing is more suited to a component (http://vuejs.org/guide/index.html#Components).

You would declare a component with a `template` attribute that either inline or via reference to a `<script>` style template would have markup that would include usage of `v-repeat`.